# Mutliple records match one column but filter on other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am not really even sure how to ask this but let me give it a go.

I have a table, let's call it widgets. Within this table for each widget I will have several records which include various data but each of the records for this widget will have the same widget identifier.

How can I only select this widget if one of the records contains some other specific data.

Example:

```
---------------------------------
| widgetid | status             |
|--------------------------------
| 54345    | added to inventory |
|-------------------------------|
| 54345    | sold               |
|-------------------------------|
| 58879    | added to inventory |
---------------------------------
```

So, in the above table, I would only wan to SELECT the 54345 widget since it's the only one that has a matching "sold" status.

The problem here is that I will not know the widget id at the time of the query because it's dynamically generated.

I am sure I am missing something monumentally stupid but after messing with this for a while and finding no help search, I thought it was time to throw it out there and see what you good people think.

Using MySQL if that matters.

Comment: `SELECT widgetid FROM status = 'sold'`

Comment: Round here, you tend to get what you ask for ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT w1.*
FROM Widgets w1
JOIN Widgets w2
ON w1.widgetid = w2.widgetid
WHERE w2.status = "sold"
```

Comment: Going to try this too, just need a little time to test it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT widgetid FROM widgets WHERE status= 'sold'
```

This could do it for you

Comment: This doesn't return the other rows for that widget.

Comment: SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE status= 'sold'

Comment: That still won't return the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
SELECT widgetid 
FROM widgets
WHERE status='sold'
```

Comment: This doesn't return the other rows for that widget.

Comment: yes, didnt think to that... then it should be - SELECT * From... Thanx for pointing that @Barmar.. :)

Answer (score 0):

DevZer0's solution not only contains a bug (the table name is missing) it would also only return the record with the "sold" status. I assume you're after ALL the records with a widgetid for which there is a "sold" status. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE widgetid IN (SELECT widgetid FROM widgets WHERE status = 'sold')
```

Comment: MySQL optimizes `WHERE ... IN (SELECT` poorly. Better to use my `JOIN` solution.

Comment: Going to try this one, just need a little time to adapt it to my setup. Will let you know how it works out. Thanks to all for all the quick answers..

Comment: Barmar could be right. I don't know any MySQL. Functionally his and my statement do the same. Any SQL compliant database would return the same result. Optimization however is database dependent. PostgreSQL, Oracle and MSSQL have no problem optimizing my statement, but as Barmar indicates MySQL apparently has.